# Работа с XML в C++ Builder 6

Tags: xml, c++builder, c++

```
XMLDocument1->LoadFromFile("http://...");
_di_IXMLNode node = XMLDocument1->ChildNodes->FindNode("...");
```

Это показалось мне самым простым способом парсинга XML.

Проблема заключается в: На своем ПК запускаю приложение - работает отлично, у некоторых друзей тоже работает нормально, но на некоторых компьютерах вылетает "для запрошенного ресурса данные недоступны". Немного покопавшись понял что ПК, где вылетает ошибка, просто не подключается к интернету (хотя интернет есть). Может надо что-то указать в программе для соединения с интернетом, что на некоторых ПК включено по дефолту?

Answer (score 1):

А как Вы линковали OBJ с пакетами и библиотеками? Если - с RUNTIME-овскими, то, может быть, их нет на тех компах, где не идет Ваша программа. Запустите TDUMP.EXE Вашей программы и просмотрите импорты, а потом поищите их на тех компах

Comment: Я перед компеляцией убираю динамические библиотеки, и понял что он вбирает в себя их.

Если это не так - как можно импортировать библиотеки на другой компьютер?

Comment: А пакеты тоже убираете? 
Устанавливаются они, обычно, в ..\system32. У Вас они именно там. Впрочем, установить можно куда угодно, только потом следует дополнить переменные окружения этим путем.

Comment: Если не трудно, опишите процесс переноса необходимых файлов.
что, куда и т.д.

Я начинающий в этом деле и пока многое не ясно.
Заранее спасибо.


Говорят, что на делфи помогает

    soapclient1.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True